# Get variable isn't written to database

Tags: php

I've got this code

```
$cislonakupu=$_GET['cislonakupu'];

    if($_REQUEST['command']=='update'){
        $datum = Date("j/m/Y H:i:s", Time());
    $user1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE `username`='$session'");
    $mu=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `velikostiobj` WHERE `objednavkac`='$cislonakupu'");$cislonakupu=$_GET['cislonakupu'];

        $customerid=mysql_insert_id();
        $date=date('Y-m-d');
        $orderid=mysql_insert_id();

        $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
        for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
            $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
            $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
            $price=get_price($pid);
            $cp=$_POST['cp'];
        $velikots=$row['velikost'];

$n= date('j/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($Date. ' + 14 days'));

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($mu)) {

                        $resultik=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `objednavkyinfo`(cislonakupu,produkt,mnozstvi,cena,cislofaktury,username,datumnakupu,dorucitdodata,velikost,dorucspol) VALUES ('$cislonakupu','$pid','$q','$price','$cislofaktury','$session','$datum','$n','$velikots','$cp')") or die(mysql_error());
}

        }
        header("Location: shoppingcart.php?delete=ano");


    }
```

I need to write `$velikots` to and database.

If `$velikots="Some text";` - It's working

If `$velikots=$row['velikost'];` - Not working

Where's the problem?

Comment: Just so you know, your code is vulnerable to SQL-injection.

Comment: @Max : Yes, I know, I am solving this problem first, then the SQLI security

Comment: Why don't you use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` instead of the loop?

Comment: what's wrong with that code

Comment: $velikots=$row['velikost']; this line has to be inside while loop.

Answer (score 2):

<s>You never fetch your results</s>. You are trying to use the results of your query before you actually fetch them from your database.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mu);
$velikots = $row['velikost'];
```

You should then be able to remove your while loop:

```
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($mu)) { ... } // remove this.
```

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). **You are also wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**

Comment: He has `while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($mu)) {`. The problem is that this is after the assignment.

Comment: Ahh. I missed that when scanning the code. Reformulating answer.

Comment: Hmm, It still doesn't write $velikots into database

Comment: There you go. There's no value. So it makes sense why you see what you are seeing.

Comment: Sorry, am just 16 and I am not very good in PHP, but , if 
$velikots fetches data from database, these data has to be writable to other database too, am I right?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. But basically if that field in the database is empty the PHP variable you assign it to will also be empty.

Comment: Okey, I understand. So, where is mistake in that code? Because, I don't see any reason why $velikots should not have any data.

Comment: That code is fine. Check your database to make sure that column has a value in it. If it doesn't, check the code that populates it as that is where your error lies.